# Passing quantity for shopping cart in php

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, twig

I have this kind of a dataset in my process to prepare a shopping cart

[image]

Apart from quantity everything comes from the db here, when add to cart it successfully passes #id with it but for number of hours i have been unable to find a way to pass the quantity along with it...so can somebody please find me a way to do this

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}


{% block body %}


    <h2 class="page-header">Book List</h2>
    <table class="table table-striped">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>#</th>
         <th>Book Title</th>
         <th>Catogory</th>
         <th>Price</th>
         <th>Quantity</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    {% for booklist in booklist %}
      <tr>
         <th scope="row">{{booklist.id}}</th>
         <td>{{booklist.bookname}}</td>
         <td>{{booklist.category}}</td>
         <td>{{booklist.price}}</td>
         <td><input type="text" class="number quantity" id="quantity" name="quantity" value="1" required></td>
         <td>
         <a href="/Booklist/details/{{booklist.id}}" class="btn btn-success">Add to Cart</a>
         <a href="/Booklist/edit/{{booklist.id}}" class="btn btn-default">Check</a>
         </td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
   </tbody>
</table>


{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I dont see a `<form......>` tag in there anywhere

Comment: Or you are going to have to write some AJAX Code

Comment: no this is in a table i have populated data from the db, in it i have put the quantity field.. can you plleeaase guide me on this.. with the easieest method i should use

Comment: You either have to create a `<form ...> ... </form>`  for each quantity/id or pass the data using an AJAX call. As the Quantity is entered on the browser that is the only way to pass this value back to the PHP form

Comment: Same tuto-request-question as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51501746/symfony-twig-passing-two-values-in-the-url-and-one-from-a-text-field) posted 3 hours ago?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be no `<form>` so I'm wondering how you are seeing this:

> "when add to cart it successfully passes #id with it."

Since your "add-to-cart" is an `<a>` tag and not an `<input type="submit" value="Submit">` button for submitting regular forms, I'm wondering if you have some AJAX sending the request for you?

Generally, you submit form data with simple HTML, sending everything between the `<form>` tags:

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey"><br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Or using AJAX (this example uses jQuery):

```
$.post( "test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" })
  .done(function( data ) {
    alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
  });
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: As the examples in here bear NO relevance to the question I would bet that they mean next to nothing to the OP

Comment: I'd argue there's relevance - OP wants to know why his form data isn't being sent. I'm telling OP how form data is usually wrapped in form tags, or otherwise sent using AJAX, while giving examples of this.